# How can I use readline-sync npm repository with WebStorm?

Tags: node.js, npm, webstorm, tty

I wrote the following code using 'readline-sync' dependency.

```
var readlineSync = require('readline-sync');
function main() {
    printMenu();
    var userName = readlineSync.question('Please enter your choice:');
    console.log(userName);
}
main();
```

I ran this code from WebStorm trying to use the WebStorm console window. 
I got the error:

> Error: The current environment doesn't support interactive reading
>   from TTY. stty: when specifying an output style, modes may not be set

When I run it from linux terminal the code works with no error. I understand from the error message that 'readline-sync' cannot work from WebStorm console. Do you have any idea how to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

I found out the answer.

1. type in WebStorm terminal: 
   $ node --debug-brk 
   Web storm will give you the port number the debugger is listening to. On my machine it was 5858. Then press 'Ctrl+C'.
2. Create a new debugging configuration as the following one: 
   [image]
3. In WebStorm terminal type again: "$ node --debug-brk main.js "
4. put a breakpoint somewhere.
5. Click the debugging icon
   [image]

Happy Debugging!

Comment: Where do you find the "Node.js Remote Debug" configuration in the Jetbrains "new configuration dialog?"